# Future <List <String>> returns null when iterate list of images

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to get the result of the transformPhotos function which should give me a list of images in base64 (it does) but when I get it in the next function it throws []

```
Future<List<String>> transformPhotos() async {
  List<String> imagesToBase64 = [];
  if (_images.length > 0) {
    _images.forEach((File imageFile) async {
      imagesToBase64.add(await utils.imageToBase64(imageFile));
    });
  }
  return imagesToBase64;
}
```

```
Future<void> uploadPhotos() async {
  transformPhotos().then((onValue) {
    print(onValue); //throws []
  });
}
```

I expect a result like the following: `[String, String, String]`

Greetings and thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try `List<String> imagesToBase64 = List<String>();` instead of `List<String> imagesToBase64 = [];` ??

Comment: yep still throws []

Comment: Using debug, to check if the `_images` contains elements of not!, or give here some code to explain more about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that populates the list is asynchronous: `imagesToBase64.add(await utils.imageToBase64(imageFile));`

But you are returning the list without waiting for the asynchronous computations to finish. Basically, `return imagesToBase64;` is called before any value is added to it, and is therefore empty. Try something of this sort:

```
return Future.forEach(_images, (File imageFile) async {
  imagesToBase64.add(await utils.imageToBase64(imageFile));
}).then((_) => imagesToBase64);
```